Unable to set TLS/SSL Certificate for mqtt_browser_client
My task is simple, I want to communicate with Azure Event Grid Namespace Topic using flutter application developed for web (Chrome/Edge). I am unable to add SecurityContext to mqtt_browser_client.
Approach:
I have tried the example of mqtt_server_client_secure.dart and it thrown me the error as below:

So I changed to mqtt_browser_client.dart which resulted in running code but now I want to add the TLS security for the same.
Issue facing:
When I try to add this: final context = SecurityContext.defaultContext; I am again getting the error as above. So, I am assuming that the browser does not support the SecurityContext.
If the browser does not support this, then how can I be able to connect using certificate? Is there any other approach to connect to Event Grid Namespace topic? Please note that I need to connect to Event Grid Name Space Topic. I am open to discuss the other way round.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can not pass client TLS certificates to a Javascript client running in the browser.
The browser can only use certificate/key pairs that are pre-stored in it's certificate trust store.
Browser based clients tend to use authentication appraoches based on things like URL signing.

Hi hardillb, I'm using Flutter with dart but not JS. I'm sorry if I am wrong but JS is related to the flutter? I just wanted to develop flutter web application in edge/chrome. There is example provided for mobile application which uses x509 certificate authentication but there is no example for browser web application. If I try to mimic the same code (I'm new to dart) the above attached error is coming. I repeated just to clear my question further.

It doesn't matter what language you start with, if it's running the browser it will be compiled to Javascript in the end. The reason there are no examples for the web is because it just won't work.

Okay thank you for the clarification. What I am trying to do exactly is to authenticate event grid namespace topic in Azure through browser we application. How can I do that? Is there any reference to that?
